# Spark Standalone Cluster - Slave not connecting to Master

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to setup a Spark standalone cluster following the official documentation.

My master is on a local vm running ubuntu and I also have one worker running in the same machine. It is connecting and I am able to see its status in the WebUI of the master.

Here is the WebUi image -

[image]

But when I try to connect a slave from another machine, I am not able to do it.

This is the log message I get in the worker when I start from another machine.
I have tried using `start-slaves.sh` from the master after updating conf\slaves and also `start-slave.sh spark://spark:7077` from the slave.

[Master hostname - spark; Worker hostanme - worker]

```
15/07/01 11:54:16 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@spark:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@spark:7077]].
15/07/01 11:54:59 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/07/01 11:54:59 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

When I try to telnet from the slave to the master, this is what I get -

```
root@worker:~# telnet spark 7077
Trying 10.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to spark.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Telnet seems to work but the connection is closed as soon as it is established. Could this have something to do with the problem ?

I have added the master and slave IP addresses in /etc/hosts on both machines.
I followed all the solutions given at [SPARK + Standalone Cluster: Cannot start worker from another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822222/spark-standalone-cluster-cannot-start-worker-from-another-machine)
but they have not worked for me.

I have the following config set in spark-env.sh in both machines -

> export SPARK_MASTER_IP=spark
>
> export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=44444

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

I encounter the exact same problem as you and just figure out how to get it to work.

The problem is that your spark master is listening on hostname, in your example **spark**, which causes the worker on the same host being able to register successfully but failed from another machine with command `start-slave.sh spark://spark:7077`.

The solution is to make sure the value *SPARK_MASTER_IP* is specified with ip in file *conf/spark-env.sh*

```
    SPARK_MASTER_IP=<your host ip>
```

on your master node, and start your spark master as normal. You can open your web GUI to make sure your spark master appears as *spark://YOUR_HOST_IP:7077* after the start. Then, on another machine with command `start-slave.sh spark://<your host ip>:7077`
should start and register worker to master successfully.

Hope it would help you

Comment: Solution didn't work, but at least gives me a different error.

Comment: did you do the password less authentication to the slave machine ?. if not master=slave communication is not possible

Comment: Thanks. changed to SPARK_MASTER_HOST on latest versions

Answer (score 14):

Its depends on your spark version, it will need different conf.
if your spark version 1.6 add this line to `conf/spark-env.sh`so another machine can connect to master

> SPARK_MASTER_IP=your_host_ip

and if your spark version is 2.x add these lines to your `conf/spark-env.sh`

> SPARK_MASTER_HOST=your_host_ip
>
> SPARK_LOCAL_IP=your_host_ip

after adding these lines run spark :

> ./sbin/spark-all.sh

and if you do right , you can see in `<your_host_ip>:8080` that spark master url is:`spark://<your_host_ip>:7077`

BeCarefule your_host_ip ,shouldnt be `localhost` and It must be exactly `Your host ip` that you set in `conf/spark-env.sh`

after all you can connect another machine to the master with command below:

> ./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://your_host_ip:7077

Comment: This also worked for me on Spark 2.0.1.  

Before this change the URL was spark://spark-master:7077 after it was spark://IP:7077.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer just saved me a lot of frustration. I have been trying to debug the issue for the last 2 days and nowhere could I see that the SPARK_MASTER_IP parameter was changed to SPARK_MASTER_HOST in spark version 2.x. It is ridiculous that it is not mentioned anwhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just launched my own spark cluster with version 2.10. The way I solved my problem is the following:

```
 ./sbin/start-master.sh -h <your_ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

All solutions above didn't work for me, but I found one more way to fix problem: [Stackoverflow: spark worker not connecting to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056868/spark-worker-not-connecting-to-master/41057499)

> Please check configuration file "**spark-env.sh**" on your **master node**. Have you set the **SPARK_MASTER_HOST** variable to the IP address of the master node? If not try to set it and restart the master and slaves. For example, if your master node's IP is 192.168.0.1, you should have SPARK_MASTER_HOST=192.168.0.1 in there. Note that you don't need to set this variable on your slaves.

Answer (score 0):

1. Under the spark/conf directory, open the file `spark-defaults.conf.template` to edit.
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   spark.master spark://your hostname:7077
   ```

To find your hostname, type `hostname` in your command prompt.