# Setting up spark cluster on Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, windows-10

I am trying to setup a spark 3 luster using two systems running windows 10. I was able to start master using

`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h <hostname>` which starts the master at `spark://<hostname>:7077`

On the second machine which I am trying to use as worker node I am using
`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<hostname>:7077` however it throws a connection refused error.

I followed the link [spark start-slave not connecting to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335674/spark-start-slave-not-connecting-to-master) , [Spark Standalone Cluster - Slave not connecting to Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166851/spark-standalone-cluster-slave-not-connecting-to-master) and updated the spark-env file to update the `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` and `SPARK_LOCAL_IP`  but still no luck.

I tried to use `-i flag` when starting the master and I was able to successfully connect both master and slave nodes however spark documentation says that -i has been deprecated so can some one please point out what I am doing wrong when using `-h flag` on starting the master.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide master host name or IP to Worker: by passing:

```
...Worker spark://<MASTER IP>:7077
```

Comment: Yes I am doing that  with  the command   spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<hostname>:7077