# Pyspark CLI Error

Tags: pyspark

I need to connect to HIVE from PySpark. I'm trying to run pyspark from CLI

spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=MY_IP
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/app/spark/tmp
```

Facing the below exception while running the pyspark

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/03/28 15:29:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/03/28 15:29:51 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, PC_NAME resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using MY_IP instead (on interface eth1)
18/03/28 15:29:51 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
18/03/28 15:29:52 WARN client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This post will help to solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166851/spark-standalone-cluster-slave-not-connecting-to-master