# Why can't standalone slaves connect to master on separate Mac OS boxes?

Tags: macos, networking, apache-spark

I have two Macs (both OS X EI Caption) at home, both are connected to same wifi. I want to install an spark cluster (with two workers) on this two computers.

Mac1 (192.168.1.2) is my master, with Spark 1.5.2, it is up and working well, and I can see the Spark UI at http://localhost:8080/  (also I see spark://Mac1:7077)

I also have run one slave on this machine (Mac1), and I see it under workers in the Spark UI.

Then, I have copied the Spark on the second machine (Mac2), and I am trying to run another Slave on Mac2 (192.168.2.9) by this command:

```
./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://Mac1:7077
```

But, it does not work: Looking at log it shows:

```
Failed to connect to master Mac1:7077
Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkMaster@Mac1:7077/),Path(/User/Master)]
```

Networking-wise, at Mac1, I can SSH to Mac2, and vice versa, but I cannot telnet to Mac1:7077.

I will appreciate it if you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `-h` option for `./sbin/start-master.sh`, i.e. `./sbin/start-master.sh -h Mac1`

Optionally, you could do `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://192.168.1.2:7077` instead.

The reason is that binding to ports in Spark is very sensitive to what names and IPs are used. So, in your case, 192.168.1.2 != Mac1. They're different "names" in Spark, and that's why you can use `ssh` successfully as it uses name resolver on OS while it does not work at Spark level where the above condition holds, i.e. the "names" are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a networking/firewall issue on the mac.

Also, your error message you copy/pasted reference port 7070.  is this the issue?

Answer (score 0):

using IP addresses in conf/slaves works somehow, but I have to use IP everywhere to address the cluster instead of host name.

[SPARK + Standalone Cluster: Cannot start worker from another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822222/spark-standalone-cluster-cannot-start-worker-from-another-machine)